# Filtering part of a list?

Tags: python, string, list, filtering

Let's say that I ask for input and the user enters:

```
"RED REDD REDDD REDDDDD"
```

I convert the string into a list, named `red`.
`red[0] = 'RED', red[1] = 'REDD'` and so forth.

How do I get it so that it ONLY displays the letter `D`, and removes everything else? So then `red[0]` would be `D`, `red[1]` would be `DD` and so forth. Is there a method for this? Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `re.sub`; replace everything other than `'D'` with `''`.

```
>>> import re
>>> strs = "RED REDD REDDD REDDDDD ABCDeeeeDDDDDDDD ABCD"
>>> [re.sub(r'[^D]+', r'', item) for item in strs.split()]
['D', 'DD', 'DDD', 'DDDDD', 'DDDDDDDDD', 'D']
```

or:

```
>>> re.sub(r'[^D\s]+', r'', strs).split()
['D', 'DD', 'DDD', 'DDDDD', 'DDDDDDDDD', 'D']
```

Comment: From looking at that it seems to only filter "RE". If the user enters ABCDDDD it has to be able to remove "ABC" and only print out the D's - if that makes sense

Comment: @R337 expected output for `ABCDeeeeDDDDDD`?

Comment: Expected output for ABCDeeeeDDDDDD would be DDDDDDD

Comment: @R337 Just clarifying, you realise that there are six trailing `D`s and your expected result is 7?

Answer (score 3):

You have many options, some already noted in other answers, as well as these:

regex for pattern matching

```
import re
s = "RED REDD REDDD REDDDDD"
pattern = r'D+' 
re.findall(pattern, s)
```

string operations

```
[''.join([c for c in x if c=='D']) for x in s.split()]
```

Comment: What if `s = "DREAD DREADD DREADDD DREADDDDD"`?

Comment: The question needs to be better specified, then; he doesn't say what he wants in that case except 'it ONLY displays the letter D'

Comment: Look at the comments on Ashwini's answer

Comment: I changed the comprehension, but I like Ashwini's answer for regex.

Answer (score 1):

My solutions may seem less readable and straightforward than the above, but they show some alternative approaches that may make you think differently about what you're trying to do in the first place. At very least, these differ from using a regular expression or list comprehension in that they should work very well with large inputs, producing the groups you want only when you ask for them.

#### itertools.groupby

```
from itertools import groupby
# Groups of adjacent letters 'D' and not 'D'
g = groupby("RED REDD REDDD REDDDD", lambda c:c=='D')
# Literally what you asked for:
[''.join(i[1]) for i in g if i[0]]
```

#### collections.Counter

```
from collections import Counter
words = "RED REDD REDDD REDDDD".split()
# for large input: (i[itertools.groupby("RED REDD REDDD REDDDD", lambda c:c!=' '))
counters = (Counter(w) for w in words)
# Literally what you asked for:
[c['D']*'D' for c in counters]
```